# Class instantiated in another and needing an object of the second class

Tags: python, class

I have class `Class2` initializing with a string `my_string` and an instance of another class `Class1`. This `Class1` initialize with a method `method` which needs `my_string`.

I wrote what I find the easiest but I have a feeling this is not the best option. Is there a better practice than the following MWE?

**EDIT:**
Following the comment from jonrsharpe, I propose a second MWE.

**EDIT 2:**
The class describes below are minimalistic. The classes in my code contains several methods acting on the objects in the class.

**MWE 1**

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self,object_class):
        self.method(object_class)
        
    def method(self,object_class):
        print(object_class.my_string)
        
        
class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_string="abc"
        self.my_class=Class1(self)
        
        
test=Class2()
```

or

**MWE 2**

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self,some_string):
        self.method(some_string)
        
    def method(self,some_string):
        print(some_string)
        
        
class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_string="abc"
        self.my_class=Class1(self.my_string)
        
        
test=Class2()
```

Comment: "Better practice" is a matter of context and opinion, from such a generic example it's hard to say. But certainly I would consider the relationship between `Class1` and `Class2` overcomplicated - I'd generally avoid creating instances of collaborators in `__init__` methods as much as possible, because that leads to high coupling and hard testing, and have dependencies in a single direction.

Comment: So it would be best to pass only `my_object` to `Class1`? I will modify the MWE.

Comment: Well, _maybe_ - we don't have the context of the actual situation you're trying to model to tell that.

Comment: If your classes really need to be tightly coupled (usage of a class dependency instead of primitives), I would suggest the use of inheritance as per my answer. If you can depend on primitives (strings, integers, ...) instead of class instances, then you can pass the string as an argument to another class.

Comment: `Class2` is my application class and `Class1` is my class containing methods for a MVC architecture. `my_string` is in fact a path needed by the method.

Comment: Right now `Class2` seems to have no point at all. It doesn't use either attribute, except to pass the string to a new `Class1` instance. Why not just `Class1("abc")`? For that matter why isn't `Class1` simply a function (see: ["stop writing classes"](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html)) that prints its argument (which is... `print`)? This is what I mean about context.

Comment: I get your point regarding the MWE I am showing but with the complete code it makes sense to use classes as I need to call several instances of said classes which contains many attributes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of inheritance? Maybe this will not suit your use case, which I do not know (at the time of the answer context is unknown), but for the example above I would do it like this to decouple instance dependency:

```py
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_string = "abc"


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method(self):
        print(self.my_string)


test = ChildClass()
test.method()
```